# Why it needs to set associations from both the sides?

Tags: hibernate, orm

Suppose, if I have a entity `Employee` and `Department` with one-to-many relationship then, if I want to save these entities, I need to set it like

```
employee.setDepartment(department);
```

and

```
department.getEmployees().add(employee);
```

Why it needs to set this association from both the sides?

Comment: In this case, when you are in **one-to-many** relationship in one side then you mush having **many-to-one** relationship in another side. You can refer [this](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/) for a better understanding.

Comment: You don't need to. What matters for hibernate is the owner side: the side which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. All you *need* is employee.setDepartment(department). But it's indeed a good idea to initialize both sides and thus not have an incoherent object graph.